# Add a citation the first time a glossary entry is used?

Tags: citing, glossaries

Is it possible to add a `\cite` upon the first appearance of a `\gls` entry? Or do I have to do this manually? For example, could I automatically add a citation of some AIDS paper the first time I use the abbreviation AIDS?

```
\gls{AIDS}\cite{some important paper about AIDS}
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible, e.g. with the `glossaries-extra` package. But please show us what you've got so far (MWE).

Comment: @TeXnician the above is what I have so far. I'll check the `glossaries-extra` package and post an answer, once I've figured it out. Thanks for pointing me to this package.